# How does one take complete control of the MacBook built-in webcam?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, command-line, software-recommendation, webcam

Zoom is able to adjust the MacBook Pro's built-in camera (I think it raises the ISO) for low lighting, either automatically or manually (user-controlled). This is the only application I am aware of that can change any of the camera's settings.
I would like to be able to take full control of the video settings (i.e. brightness, contrast, color temperature, ISO, [digital] shutter speed, iris/aperture, etc.) on the MacBook's built-in webcam.

Are there any apps, utilities, terminal commands, plugins, frameworks, etc. that can allow me to customize said settings for all video outputs?

Comment: Teams can also make the focus move to follow a face / body...

Comment: I’ve changed up the tags and focused on the one question. We can link to an audio routing question if you want that tie in. Ecamm Live and OBS are the leaders there IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best software for this is written by [ecamm - iGlasses for Mac](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/iglasses/)

Their iGlasses product works very well and describes all the ways in which you can and can not take control of the physical camera based on hardened apps in Big Sur, Catalina and Mojave and making a virtual software camera to feed to other apps.

- https://support.ecamm.com/en/articles/3217016-iglasses-compatibility-with-apps

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Webcam Settings](http://mactaris.blogspot.com) which you can get from the Apple App Store for US$8.  It directly adjusts the webcam (don't ask me how!) and so works with all webcam apps.  I have had no issues with Big Sur upgrade.

You will not be able to adjust everything in your list and what can be adjusted varies by webcam.  For example, it can adjust more on my Logitech webcam than the built-in webcam.

Here is the main settings panel for my built-in camera:

[image: Settings for FaceTime HD Camera]

The Hue and White Balance settings will likely be enough to make a significant improvement.

But no app will magically make a relatively poor web cam into a great looking one. If you find the built-in FaceTime webcam is not good enough for your usage, you should invest in a better one.  I use a rather old Logitech C920 which is better than the built-in and you can easily find a webcam that is better again.

Comment: It's not the webcam that's the problem; it's how it doesn't let me disable the automatic stuff, like how Magic Lantern is able to hack into the color temperature, ISO, and shutter speed settings to remove the restrictions of affixed/notched values.

But thanks for the recommendation you provided. It seems like it can do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

A freeware option that has some color-correction and brightness/contrast features is [SplitCam](https://splitcam.com/features).  It's compatible with Zoom, but requires you to run the virtual-camera driver and have SplitCam running.

[image: SplitCam color-adjustment feature description]